# Multiplying just one column from each of the 2 input DataFrames together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latency

I have two DataFrames that are each of the exact sane dimensions and I would like to multiply just one specific column from each of them together:

My first DataFrame is:

```
In [834]: patched_benchmark_df_sim
Out[834]: 
     build_number      name  cycles
0             390     adpcm   21598
1             390       aes    5441
2             390  blowfish     NaN
3             390     dfadd     463
....
284           413      jpeg  766742
285           413      mips    4263
286           413     mpeg2    2021
287           413       sha  348417

[288 rows x 3 columns]
```

My second DataFrame is:

```
In [835]: patched_benchmark_df_syn
Out[835]: 
     build_number      name    fmax
0             390     adpcm  143.45
1             390       aes  309.60
2             390  blowfish     NaN
3             390     dfadd  241.02
....
284           413      jpeg  197.75
285           413      mips  202.39
286           413     mpeg2  291.29
287           413       sha  243.19

[288 rows x 3 columns]
```

And I would like to take each element of the `cycles` column of `patched_benchmark_df_sim` and multiply that to the corresponding element of the `fmax` column of `patched_benchmark_df_syn`, and then store the result in a new DataFrame that has exactly the same structure, contiaining the `build_number` and `name` columns, but now the last column containing all the numerical data will be called `latency`, which is the product of `fmax` and `cycles`.

So the output DataFrame has to look something like this:

```
    build_number      name    latency
0            390     adpcm    ## each value here has to be product of cycles and fmax and they must correspond to one another ##
......
```

I tried doing a straightforward `patched_benchmark_df_sim * patched_benchmark_df_syn` but that did not work as my DataFrames had the `name` column that's of string type. Is there no builtin pandas method that can do this for me? How could I proceed with the multiplication to get the result I need?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to add a new column to the df and then select the columns you want and if you want assign that to a new df:

```
In [356]:

df['latency'] = df['cycles'] * df1['fmax']
df
Out[356]:
     build_number      name  cycles       latency
0             390     adpcm   21598  3.098233e+06
1             390       aes    5441  1.684534e+06
2             390  blowfish     NaN           NaN
3             390     dfadd     463  1.115923e+05
284           413      jpeg  766742  1.516232e+08
285           413      mips    4263  8.627886e+05
286           413     mpeg2    2021  5.886971e+05
287           413       sha  348417  8.473153e+07
In [357]:

new_df = df[['build_number', 'name', 'latency']]
new_df
Out[357]:
     build_number      name       latency
0             390     adpcm  3.098233e+06
1             390       aes  1.684534e+06
2             390  blowfish           NaN
3             390     dfadd  1.115923e+05
284           413      jpeg  1.516232e+08
285           413      mips  8.627886e+05
286           413     mpeg2  5.886971e+05
287           413       sha  8.473153e+07
```

As you've found you can't multiply non-numeric type df's together like you tried. The above is assuming that the build_number and name columns are the same from both dfs.

Comment: Yes this works great! As you mentioned, it only works if build_number and name columns are same in both dfs. That's why I implemented a lot of pre-processing steps related to some of my earlier posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735609/cryptic-warning-pops-up-when-doing-pandas-assignment-with-loc-and-iloc to actually fill up missing benchmark names and build_numbers with NaN so that they two frames can be nicely multiplied together.